# Open tab, set it's title and execute command with Guake

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, shell

Is there a way to programmatically make [Guake](https://github.com/Guake/guake) to:

- Open new tab
- Set's it title to the specified string
- Execute a specified command in it?

I just can't figure out the correct [CLI arguments](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-guake/) to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-n` - new tab

`-r` - title for the new tab

`-e` - execute command

Example:

`guake -n " " -r "My Tab" -e "uname -a"`

More info under `guake -h`